# difference between ddply and aggregate

Tags: r

Can someone help me get the difference between aggregate and ddply with the following example:

A data frame:

```
mydat <- data.frame(first = rpois(10,10), second = rpois(10,10), 
                    third = rpois(10,10), group = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)))
```

Use aggregate to apply a function to a part of the data frame split by a factor:

```
aggregate(mydat[,1:3], by=list(mydat$group), mean)
  Group.1 first second third
1       a   8.8    8.8  10.2
2       b   6.8    9.4  13.4
```

Try to use aggregate for another function (returns an error message):

```
aggregate(mydat[,1:3], by=list(mydat$group), function(u) cor(u$first,u$second))
Error in u$second : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Now, try the same with ddply (plyr package):

```
ddply(mydat, .(group), function(u) cor(u$first,u$second))
  group         V1
1     a -0.5083042
2     b -0.6329968
```

All tips, links, criticism are highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you've demonstrated the difference.  Or is there a question here?

Comment: Well, while I see there is a difference, I don't understand why it is so. What within these functions causes the difference I show?

Comment: Part 5 of http://programming-r-pro-bro.blogspot.com/2012/12/r-faqs-for-fresh-starters.html has an awesome explanation with sample code. Basically, ddply will allow you to use DIFFERENT functions on each variable, whereas aggregate forces you to use the same function on all columns you pass.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`aggregate` calls FUN on each column independently, which is why you get independent means.  `ddply` is going to pass all columns to the function.  A quick demonstration of what is being passed in `aggregate` may be in order:

Some sample data for demonstration:

```
d <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8, c=c(1,1,2,2))

> d
  a b c
1 1 5 1
2 2 6 1
3 3 7 2
4 4 8 2
```

By using the function `print` and ignoring the result of the commands `aggregate` or `ddply`, we can see what gets passed to the function in each iteration.

`aggregate`:

```
tmp <- aggregate(d[1:2], by=list(d$c), print)
[1] 1 2
[1] 3 4
[1] 5 6
[1] 7 8
```

Note that individual columns are sent to print.

`ddply`:

```
tmp <- ddply(d, .(c), print)
  a b c
1 1 5 1
2 2 6 1
  a b c
3 3 7 2
4 4 8 2
```

Note that data frames are being sent to print.

Comment: Cool, thanks: the first two sentences contain exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Arun What I pasted is the output from `print` within `aggregate`.  I omitted the result from `aggregate` which is not important for this example.  I'll edit the answer to better indicate this.

Answer (score 9):

You've already been told why `aggregate` was the wrong {base} function to use for a function that requires two vectors as arguments, but you haven't yet been told which non-ddply approach would have succeeded.

The `by( ... grp, FUN)` method:

```
> cbind (by( mydat, mydat["group"], function(d) cor(d$first, d$second)) )
        [,1]
a  0.6529822
b -0.1964186
```

The `sapply(split( ..., grp), fn)` method

```
> sapply(  split( mydat, mydat["group"]), function(d) cor(d$first, d$second)) 
         a          b 
 0.6529822 -0.1964186
```

Comment: I always feel guilty when I resort to `plyr/ddply`, because I means I failed or was too impatient understanding aggregate, by, or tapply. Note however that `ddply` is so general it can be slow for large problems. A fast version of ddply is in growing here: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr .

Answer (score 7):

The answer of @MatthewLundberg, is very good , mine it is not an answer but it is just a general hint that I use when I want to see what happen behind some R functions call. I use the debug command `browser`.

```
aggregate(mydat[,1:3], by=list(mydat$group), 
+           function(x){
+             browser()
+             mean(x)
+           })
Called from: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
Browse[1]> x
[1] 16 10 16 13 25
```

then for ddply

```
ddply(mydat, .(group), function(u) {
+   browser()
+   cor(u$first,u$second)
+   })
Called from: .fun(piece, ...)
Browse[1]> u
  first second third group
1    16      8     9     a
2    10      6     6     a
3    16      6    10     a
4    13      8    10     a
5    25     10     4     a
```

**Edit debug the error by yourself**

Here I use the technique to see why you get an error

```
aggregate(mydat[,1:3], by=list(mydat$group), function(u) {
+   browser()
+   cor(u$first,u$second)
+   })
Called from: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
Browse[1]> u
[1] 16 10 16 13 25
```

As you see here u is an atomic vector (without column names)
So if you try

```
Browse[1]> u$first
```

You get an error :

```
Error in u$first : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```