# How to aggregate some columns while keeping other columns in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame like this:

```
     id  no  age
1    1   7   23
2    1   2   23
3    2   1   25
4    2   4   25
5    3   6   23
6    3   1   23
```

and I hope to aggregate the date frame by `id` to a form like this: (just sum the `no` if they share the same `id`, but keep `age` there)

```
    id  no  age
1    1   9   23
2    2   5   25
3    3   7   23
```

How to achieve this using R?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame is named `df`.

```
aggregate(no~id+age, df, sum)
#   id age no
# 1  1  23  9
# 2  3  23  7
# 3  2  25  5
```

Comment: This does not work as you add more columns, it treats every column on the RHS as a column of factors to group by, so for example if you include an extra column with a not for each entry, you end up with many duplicate rows as a result

Comment: What if age is not consistent for each id and we just want the first age?

Answer (score 7):

Even better, `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
# convert your object to a data.table (by reference) to unlock data.table syntax
setDT(DF)
DF[  , .(sum_no = sum(no), unq_age = unique(age)), by = id]
```

Comment: And if you haven't declared it as a `data.table` (as is likely if you're just now calling `library(data.table)`), you can use `setDT(dt)[,list(sum(no),unique(age)),by=id]`. I like `data.table`, but I don't know if I'd say this is "Even better" than the equally concise answers above :)

Comment: fair, but I mean even better in the sense that this may get you to start using `data.table`, the dividends if which are immeasurable ;-)

Comment: Why do you use `unique(age)` here? Why not just `dt[, sum(no), .(id, age)]` ? You have way too many of unnecessary keystrokes here

Comment: `dt[, sum(no), .(id, age)]` does not work for me; `Error ... could not find function "."`

Comment: also, this does not work if you want to group `by` multiple columns, and also include multiple other columns in the output

Comment: @user5359531 make sure to follow the `setDT` step. regarding your second point -- it _does_ work. but I don't know what specifically you're after.

Comment: I created a new question to illustrate the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418127/r-how-to-aggregate-some-columns-while-keeping-other-columns

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use `ddply` from plyr package:

```
require(plyr)
ddply(df,.(id,age),summarise,no = sum(no))
```

In this particular example the results are identical. However, this is not always the case, the difference between the both functions is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176756/difference-between-ddply-and-aggregate). Both functions have their uses and are worth exploring, which is why I felt this alternative should be mentioned.