# How to apply a function to grouped rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I have a data frame generated by

```
points_A = sample(1:6,6)
points_B = sample(1:6,6)
points_C = sample(1:6,6)
df <- data.frame( name = gl(3,2,labels=c("Luca","Mario","Paolo") ) , cbind(points_A,points_B,points_C)  )
```

which display as

```
   name points_A points_B points_C
1  Luca        5        2        3
2  Luca        3        3        1
3 Mario        1        5        2
4 Mario        6        6        4
5 Paolo        4        4        5
6 Paolo        2        1        6
```

I would like to apply a function (e.g. sum() ) to the rows grouped by the column name (1st column).

The output should be something like:

```
   name points_A points_B points_C
1  Luca        8        5        4
2  Mario       7       11        6
3  Paolo       6        5       11
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ name, df, sum)`, or in dplyr, `df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise_all(sum)`

Comment: `aggregate(. ~ name, df, sum)` this is working, but if I've other columns like lastname, city etc, that I still want in the dataframe but I do not want to pass to aggregate because they are another data type? Is there a way to specify what keep out?

Comment: [This solved my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978985/how-to-aggregate-some-columns-while-keeping-other-columns-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

I like to do these things with `data.table`

`library(data.table);
dt<-data.table(df) ;
dt[, function(column), by = group]`
As "column" you can also set `.SD` to get multiple columns.  "group" would be "name" in your example.

Answer (score 0):

A (pretty raw) solution with `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = name, .SDcols = 2:4]

    name points_A points_B points_C
1:  Luca        9        6        6
2: Mario        5       10       11
3: Paolo        7        5        4
```

EDIT:
A raw solution in base `R`:

```
t(sapply(split(df, df$name), function(x) colSums(x[, c("points_A", "points_B", "points_C")])))
```

Comment: Output different to to random nature of data. Better to `set.seed` in the next question.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I just thought that the result does not affect the outcome I required.