# How to keep other columns when using dplyr?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I have a similar problem as described [How to aggregate some columns while keeping other columns in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978985/how-to-aggregate-some-columns-while-keeping-other-columns-in-r), but none of the solutions from there which I have tried work.

I have a data frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame(a=rep(c("a","b"),each=2),b=c(500,400,200,300), 
               c = c(5,10,2,4),stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
> df
  a   b  c
1 a 500  5
2 a 400 10
3 b 200  2
4 b 300  4

df%>%
  group_by(a)%>%
  summarise('max' = max(c), 'sum'=sum(c))

  a       max   sum
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        10    15  
2 b         4     6

but I need also column b:

1 a        10    15   400
2 b         4     6   300
```

The value for column b is max(c).

---

Edit data for specific case:

```
> df
  a   b  c
1 a 500  5
2 a 400  5
```

in this case, I need a higher value col b in the summary

```
#   a       max   sum     b
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a         5    10   500
```

Comment: Column b has 4 values, and in your output you show 2 values. How do you decide which ones to use in the output?

Comment: I added information at the end about counting column b

Comment: Why not add them explicitly `summarise('max' = max(c), 'sum'=sum(c), 'b'=max(b))` ?

Comment: It's not good solution because then A=500, but I expected A=400

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify how to summariz the variable `b`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(max = max(c), sum = sum(c), b = max(b[c == max(c)]))

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   a       max   sum     b
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a        10    15   400
# 2 b         4     6   300
```

---

Comment: Ok, but what if the same ```c``` values are for the unique ```a```?  I edited the data last.

Answer (score 4):

I would replace the `summarise` with a `mutate` (keeps all rows), and then filter for the rows you want. The tibble is then still grouped, so an `ungroup` is needed to get rid of the groups.

```
d f%>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    mutate('max' = max(c), 'sum'=sum(c)) %>% 
    filter(c == max) %>%
    ungroup()

#   a         b     c   max   sum
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a       400    10    10    15
# 2 b       300     4     4     6
```

Comment: Ok, but what if the same c values are for the unique a? I edited the data last.

Answer (score 1):

Updated as the question was edited

```
df%>%
  group_by(a)%>%
  summarise('max' = max(c), 'sum'=sum(c), b=max(b))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   a       max   sum     b
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a        10    15   500
# 2 b         4     6   300
```