# Correlation of subsets of dataframe using aggregate

Tags: r, aggregate, correlation

I have a data frame made by row binding many data frames, each identified with a unique key. I wish to calculate the correlation coefficients for columns in each subset (using the unique key) of the big data frame. For example, using the mtcars data I might want to calculate the correlation between columns `hp` and `wt` for each unique value in column `cyl`. I could do it in a loop

```
data("mtcars")
for(i in c(4,6,8)){
temp = subset(mtcars,mtcars$cyl==i)
cor(temp$hp,temp$wt)
}
```

I think aggregate would be better, but this code doesn't work:

```
data("mtcars")
aggregate(mtcars,by=mycars$cyl,cor)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
 data("mtcars")
 library(plyr)
 ddply(mtcars, "cyl", function(x) cor(x$hp, x$wt))
```

This splits the data in `mtcars` by `cyl`, applies for each subset `x` the function `cor(x$hp, x$wt)` and then aggregates the results for each of the subsets in a data.frame.

I can highly recommend the `plyr` package. It's one of the packages I use most in R.

---

Edit: As per request, here a `dplyr` version. I have to say that I am not a big `dplyr` user, but the code should be ok.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(V1=cor(hp, wt))
```

Comment: so there is no way of dealing with this using aggregate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176756/difference-between-ddply-and-aggregate answers my question. I have accepted your answer, thanks again.

Comment: @Alex - No it's not job for `aggregate`, but for `split`. See my answer below. This is what `plyr` package tag-line is.. `split`-`apply`-`combine`

Comment: Works well. @cryo111 could you edit your answer with a `dplyr` version?

Comment: @Alex Have added a `dplyr` solution.

Answer (score 10):

In `base` R, it's job for `split` and `lapply` or `sapply`

```
lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(X) cor(X$hp, X$wt))
## $`4`
## [1] 0.1598761
## 
## $`6`
## [1] -0.3062284
## 
## $`8`
## [1] 0.01761795
## 


sapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl), function(X) cor(X$hp, X$wt))
##           4           6           8 
##  0.15987614 -0.30622844  0.01761795
```

Comment: `by` = `split` + `lapply`.